# Efficiently evaluate a triple nested summation

Tags: matrices, summation

How do you efficiently evaluate the following nested sum, perhaps as a product of matrices and/or vectors:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}\int\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j}\alpha_{k}\;\pi_{i}(s)\pi_{j}(s)\pi_{k}(s) \; d s
$$

where $\pi_j(s)$ represents a $j$-th order orthogonal polynomial and $\alpha_j$ represents its coefficients.

I'm looking for an expansion along the lines of:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{p}\int\alpha_{i}\pi_{i}(s)ds=
\mathbf{a^{T}}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{w}
$$

where for an $N-point$ quadrature rule, this becomes:

$$
\mathbf{a}=\left[\begin{array}{c} \alpha_{1}\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_{p}
\end{array}\right],\;\mathbf{w}=\left[\begin{array}{c} w_{1}\\
\vdots\\
w_{N}
\end{array}\right],\;\mathbf{P}_{ij}=\pi_{i}(s_{j}),
$$

where $i=1,\ldots, p$ and $j=1,\ldots, N$.

Here the vector $\mathbf{w}$ are quadrature weights with corresponding points $s_1, \cdots, s_N$. Then the vector-matrix-vector product above is an evaluation of a bilinear form.

Comment: Have you considered the simpler problem of a doubly nested summation of products?  There are some simple ways to express the above sum, but bringing "matrices and/or vectors" into the picture is a little bit artificial.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @hardmath. My motivation for using only matrix and/or vector products is to be able to compute the above as fast as possible -- with three sigmas this leads to three for-loops. Can you elaborate on the simple techniques used to express this sum please? (sorry I'm a bit of a novice)

Comment: I missed your edit by a couple of minutes, and what I had in mind was the product of summations that @PaulSinclair provided.  Now you have introduced an integral into the inner summation, but the nature of the integral is not fully specified.  The coefficients $\alpha_i \alpha_j \alpha_k$ are presumably constants with respect to the variable $s$ of integration, and so can be factored out.  The integral $\int \pi_i(s) \pi_j(s) \pi_k(s) ds$ is said to involve "orthogonal polynomials", but more information about these is necessary to advise you on simplification of their triple product integral.

Comment: Sure thing. For the orthogonal polynomials, I shall attempt to elaborate on that below. First let’s assume that the integrals have lower and upper bounds of [-1,1]. Let us also assume that the orthogonal polynomial in question is from the Legendre family (which is defined on [-1,1]). Now for $i=1,j=2,k=3$ for instance, the integral can be written as: \begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}\pi_{1}\left(s\right)\pi_{2}\left(s\right)\pi_{3}\left(s\right)ds = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{s}{4}\left(3s^{2}-1\right)\left(5s^{3}-3s\right)ds
\end{equation}

Comment: *and yes, the coefficients can be factored out of the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem got a bit over-simplified in its editing.  Instead of using $\alpha_i$ for essentially all the polynomial coefficients, I think we should treat the case of coefficients $a_i, b_i, c_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,p$.

In any case this "more general case" can be used for the special case.

Given that we are willing to have the integration done by quadrature, there is a significant simplification to the complexity over just evaluating the triple summation.

Let $f(s) = \sum_{i=1}^p a_i \pi_i(s)$, $g(s) = \sum_{i=1}^p b_i \pi_i(s)$, and $h(s) = \sum_{i=1}^p c_i \pi_i(s)$.  Then the revised expression is the integral of the triple product:

$$ \int f(s) g(s) h(s) ds = \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^p \sum_{k=1}^p \int a_i b_j c_k \; \pi_i(s) \pi_j(s) \pi_k(s) ds $$

A quadrature rule for the left hand side can take advantage of recursive rules for evaluating the "orthogonal polynomials" $\pi_i(s)$ at successive orders $i$ for some fixed quadrature node $s$.

It is suggested in the revised Question that an $N$-point rule will be used to evaluate/approximate the integral.  We will therefore have operational complexity of $N$ times the complexity of evaluating integrand $f(s) g(s) h(s)$, plus some linear complexity $O(N)$ for multiplying the evaluations by weights and summing up the resulting terms.

The evaluation of $f(s) g(s) h(s)$ comes down to evaluating each factor, and these share/amortize the evaluations of underlying orthogonal polynomials $\pi_i(s)$.  If the orthogonal polynomials are "[from the Legendre family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Recursive_definition)" (as suggested in the OP's Comment on the Question), then for each quadrature point $s$ we can loop through the orders $m=1,\ldots,p$ as follows:

$$ \pi_0(s) = 1 \; , \; \pi_1(s) = s $$

$$ (m+1) \pi_{m+1}(s) = (2m+1) s \;\pi_m(s) - m\;\pi_{m-1}(s) $$

On this loop we can piggyback the accumulation of sums $f(s), g(s), h(s)$ with the prescribed coefficients $a_i, b_i, c_i$ respectively.  Therefore the complexity of evaluating the integrand at one quadrature point is $O(p)$, which subsumes the constant overhead of finally multiplying the three accumulated factors, $f(s)g(s)h(s)$.

The overall complexity of this quadrature is therefore $O(pN)$, whereas a naive nested looping scheme will cost $O(p^3N)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the indices are independent, this reduces to $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^p a_i)(\sum\limits_{j=1}^p b_j)(\sum\limits_{k=1}^p c_k)$

I suppose one way of expressing it would be $A^TV B^TV C^TV$, where V is the column matrix with $v_i = 1 \,\, \forall i$

Comment: Thanks Paul! My problem however has an integral as well:\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{P}\sum_{j=i+1}^{P}\sum_{k=j+1}^{P}\int\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j}\alpha_{k}\pi_{i}\left(s\right)\pi_{j}\left(s\right)\pi_{k}\left(s\right)ds
\end{equation} I am a bit unsure how to use your approach with an appropriate quadrature rule. Here the $\pi_{k}(s)$ represents an orthogonal polynomial of order $k$, and $\alpha_{k}$ are its coefficients.